# How to refer to a local file in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, ajax, webstorm

I am working in WebStorm and I am trying to read a text file (`file.txt`) with JavaScript. I have tried doing this with Ajax, XMLHttpRequest and fetch but all of them returned an 404 error message.

This is my directory hierarchy:

[image: directory hierarchy]

**NOTE:** I am referring the file from `artikels.js` with the following code:

```
const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('GET', 'data/file.txt', false);
xhr.onload = function() {
  if (this.status == 0) {
      const resp = this.response;
      console.log(resp);
  } else {
      console.log("fail");
}};
xhr.send();
```

I have been trying to alter the link to the following forms:

```
assets/js/own/data/file.txt
/assets/js/own/data/file.txt
./data/file.txt
```

How should I write the link in order to make it work?

**SOLVED:**

The mistake I made was that I build the path to the `file.txt` starting from the artikels.js file ... after trying the `Location.pathname` method (thanks to ibrahim tanyalcin for the advice) I found out that the current location was the location of the HTML-page that had a 'link' to the `artikels.js` file and not the `artikels.js` location ...

For illustration:

[image]

Comment: @VicJordan unfortunately  it didn't work. Maybe the link that pfcodes posted, will help me. Thanks anyway

Comment: what does the `location.pathname` give on the console?

Answer (score -1):

The only absolute URL known to `XMLHttpRequest()` is URL of the document where this script runs.

So if you want to use relative URLs they should be **relative to your document's URL**.

Thus:

```
xhr.open('GET', 'assets/js/own/data/file.txt', false);
```

Or you can use root relative URLs if *assets* folder is always at the root of your site:

```
xhr.open('GET', '/assets/js/own/data/file.txt', false);
```

Comment: @VicJordan Where? This `../assets/js/own/data/file.txt` is quite far from this `assets/js/own/data/file.txt`

Comment: Please check his question. Agree with you but none of our answers are working for him :(

Comment: Then it means that the script is included from not from document at root.